# Flask-RESTPlus - Nested Fields not getting registered into SwaggerUI

Tags: python, flask-restplus

I'm trying to create a **Nested** field to a response model. I don't unserstand why the generated `swagger.json` is aware of the nested field but do not register it under `$/definitions`.

This is my Model

```
HypervisorResponse = ns.model('HypervisorResponse', {
    'name': fields.String(required=True, example='hypervisor01.xx.com'),
    'ip_addr': fields.String(required=True, example='192.168.0.0'),
    'provider': fields.String(required=True),
    'runtime': fields.Nested(
        ns.model('RuntimeResponse', {
            'uptime': fields.Integer(attribute='uptime'),
            'last_boot': fields.String(attribute='last_boot'),
            'memory_total': fields.Integer(attribute='memory_total'),
            'memory_used': fields.Integer(attribute='memory_used')
        })
    )
})
```

The outputted swagger.json is

```
        "HypervisorResponse": {
            "required": [
                "ip_addr",
                "name",
                "provider"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "example": "hypervisor01.xx.com"
                },
                "ip_addr": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "example": "192.168.0.0"
                },
                "provider": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "runtime": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/RuntimeResponse"
                }
            },
            "type": "object"
        }
```

Comment: What version are you using ? I got `RuntimeResponse` under **definitions**

Comment: @DinkoPehar i'm using version 0.12.1

Comment: I use the same version and I had it registrated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while i figured out that the NAMESPACE ordered property were the cause of it. Setting it to False solved the issue.

Comment: btw false is default here https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#flask_restplus.Namespace

Comment: Thanks!! Without this I would still be trying to debug the Nested field class.